# Add groups condition with Symfony serializer Component : delete an attribute from serialized object because of attribute value

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, symfony5

Can i add some condition with symfony/Serializer component?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", unique=true)
 * @Groups({"user_read"})
 *
 */
private $emailIsPublic;
```

if emailIsPublic== false, i want to delete this attribute from my serialized object, using "user_read" group

At worst, return a null value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the email property getter like this :

```
 public function getEmail()
 {
    if($this->getEmailIsPublic()){
       return $this->email;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [create your own normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html) and unset attributes you need.

Smth like:

```
$data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);

if ($object->isEmailIsPublic() === false)
    unset($data['emailIsPublic']);
}

return $data;
```